# 破棄ボタンを押したタイミングで保持していたviewControllerを解放したい

Tags: swift, ios

storyboardの構成は以下です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

破棄ボタンを押した時に下記の処理を入れています。

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle:nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Top")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```

しかし、以下のようにもともと表示されていたviewの上に新たなwindowが作られてしまいます。
[image: 3回破棄を繰り返した結果です。]

もともとのviewControllerを解放して、topページに遷移させるには、上記コードをどのように書き換えればよいのでしょうか？

コメントいただいたコードを追加したところ、下記のようになりました。
deinitは呼ばれ、解放はされました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードは以下のようにしました

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?
.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle:nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FBLogin")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOSでの画面遷移はViewControllerをスタック状に積み重ねることで実現されています。RootViewControllerの子孫階層のViewControllerを解放してしまえば良いので、次のようなコードで実現できるはずです。お試しください。

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?
        .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
上記コードを追加したところ、各ViewControllerのdeinitが呼ばれたのですが、一番下のViewが残ってしまいました。
画像は上に載せました。
何か解決策をご存知でしたら、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: @tails さん、「追加」ではなく、あなたが掲載された3行は全て削除して、私の書いた１行のコードだけにしてみてください。

Comment: @Pere d'OOさん、うまくいきました！ありがとうございます。いつもありがとうございます。